# How to pass HTML selected value to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass the value from my HTML select to a controller, but I am not sure why the method is not capturing the values in spite of the select id has the same name than model.

```
  [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CountryId,ProvinceId,CityId")] ads_post ads_post)
    {
        var currUser = currentUser.GetCurrUser();
        ads_post.UserId = currUser.Id;
        ads_post.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
        ads_post.SponsoredType = null;
        ads_post.PriorityType = null;


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ads_post.Add(ads_post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.PriorityType = new SelectList(db.ads_priority_plan, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.SponsoredType = new SelectList(db.ads_sponsored_plan, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.CurrencyType = new SelectList(db.ads_currency, "Id", "Name");
        return View(ads_post);
    }
```

This is the HTML

```
  <div class="row mb-3 mt-5">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label><strong>País donde quieres publicar:</strong> <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></label>
                                    <select id="CountryId" onchange="getProvices();"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label><strong>Provincia:</strong> <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></label>
                                    <select id="ProvinceId" onchange="getCities();"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label><strong>Ciudad:</strong> <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></label>
                                    <select id="CityId"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Can somebody help me out with this?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by myself, I had just to add a name attribute to the HTML and that's it.

Comment: Not yet. It needs to have 2 days minimum